# autologon to a django web app

Tags: python, django, web

I Would like to write a little django web-app to be run in my local WLAN, to allow my customers  to browse thru the offers that I made available.
The WLAN is not password protected and isolated from web.

Ideally, I would like that when a user connect to my wlan with a smartphone or tablet, he or she is been jumped directly to the offer webserver, without entering any address or url.

Is there any combination of port forwarding/triggering on the wlan router and the webserver that can accomplish this task ?

Comment: Are you talking about [Captive Portals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal) used in creating HotSpots? They are showed to users when they connect a WLAN. In hotspots the purpose is authentication but you can use them for any purpose.

Comment: Yes Hasan, just something like this, thanxx ;)
I'll look into free linux options

Answer (score 0):

I think that for this purposes you need openwrt or similar firmware for your router, or as a second solution you can make one of your computers as internet-gateway, so router will get internet from this gateway, and on a gateway there should be an app/config/etc. , which redirect user to your app, when user firstly open any page.

Comment: I'm considering as possible solution applying nodogsplash in an openwrt-hacked router, but I have no experience at all about openwrt.
I'd prefer to go with a software implementation on a linux based pc that contains both the captive portal application & the webserver...